# Visual Basic, forms not updating

Tags: visual-studio

ive been working on a project on visual basic which has multiple forms. I've come across an error recently by where if i add anything to the form it works but if i start running the program the form is the original one not the updated one. ANyone understand why this happens? thanks for the help.

Comment: what is the error, you should explain better

Comment: its not an error code. but every time i add something to the form, it doesnt appear when debugging.